# How to get multiple button values into editext then display all the values dynamically?

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, calculator

I've been creating a calculator application I don't want to keep separate field for value1 and value2. I want to calculate the value from a single edittext which contains numbers and operators i know how to parse the operators and calculate. but how to set the edittext to display and store the pressed buttons dynamically, say If i press 1 then 2 then + then 3 then 4, it should store like 12+43 and it should display like how it stored

Comment: EditText should show 12+43 ? Is this what  you want??

Answer (score 0):

When a button is clicked, you can append the result of that button to the text field, say something like:

```
public void onAddButtonClick(View v) {
    textField.setText(textField.getText() + "+");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of what a given button does, a button's listener could simply call the `append()` method of the class `EditText` or retrieve the string from it with `getText()`, modify it, then put the modified string back in the `EditText`.

For example a ln() button could do:

```
mEditText.setText("ln(" + mEditText.getText() + ")");
```

While a "+" button could do:

```
mEditText.append("+");
```